# Windows 8 rolling back updates upon login

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-update

My Windows 8 is having problems updating. After reboot, the first login results in the system rolling back the previous update.
Here is the complete log: http://pastey.org/view/52c32b89
It is too big and I couldn't format it well here. But the section I believe to be relevant is:

```
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403602_1703390125: 0x8007045b.
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403602_1988793486: 0x8007045b.
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403602_2206660937: 0x8007045b.
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403602_2384671937: 0x8007045b.
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403602_2602111640: 0x8007045b.
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403602_2766557337: 0x8007045b.
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403602_2922029110: 0x8007045b.
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403602_3265349248: 0x8007045b.
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403602_4260222522: 0x8007045b.
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403603_306806950: 0x8007045b.
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403603_589965780: 0x8007045b.
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403603_746154107: 0x8007045b.
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403603_979479821: 0x8007045b.
2014-10-20  23:02:30:553     652    bd0 Handler FATAL: Got error querying the post-reboot status for session 30403603_1234509771: 0x8007045b.
```

I'm guessing the problem lies with 'grub' in the bootsector?
How do I fix it so the systems commits the update and I no longer have to wait for it to unroll at every boot?

Comment: You stated a problem, but you did not ask a question. Perhaps you should ask a question so you don't get answers like "remove Window, reinstall grub and everything will work fine".

Comment: Okay just edited it.

Comment: I need the logs from C:\Windows\logs\CBS to see why updates fail.

Comment: @magicandre1981 http://pastey.org/view/111da99c

Comment: I can't find any errors in the log. Also share all other files from this folder.

Comment: @magicandre1981 They are very big so I added them all to a zip file and hosted it at my unviserity ftp oki? http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~vfbsilva/CBS.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the Error `ERROR_EVT_CONFIGURATION_ERROR`which means that the configuration for Windows Events is damaged.

```
2014-10-20 23:09:39, Error                 CSI    00000016@2014/10/21:01:09:39.517 (F) CMIADAPTER: Exiting with HRESULT code = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(15010).
[gle=0x80004005]
2014-10-20 23:09:39, Error      [0x01802b] CSI    0000008f (F) Failed execution of queue item Installer: Events ({3bb9fd2b-351e-4b9c-b1fc-ed0758805998}) with HRESULT HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(15010).  Failure will be ignored: The failure was encountered during rollback; installer is reliable (2)[gle=0x80004005]

C:\Users\André>err 15010
# as an HRESULT: Severity: SUCCESS (0), FACILITY_NULL (0x0), Code 0x3aa2
# for decimal 15010 / hex 0x3aa2
  ERROR_EVT_CONFIGURATION_ERROR                                  winerror.h
# Configuration error.
```

Run `regedit.exe`, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT` make a backup of this key (export it to .reg file) and delete this key now. Aftera reboot the updates should work.

Comment: It did work you are amazing!

Comment: Yes. It is amazing. I use it for fix errors on activate `Hyper-V` platform on `Windows 8.1`. In `CBS.log` I see same error - `CMIADAPTER: AI failed. HRESULT = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(15010)` after try Install `Events` for `Hyper-V`.